# How do I access a DIV from javascript, if ASP.NET mangles its ID?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, master-pages

I have a web page that contains a "div" element.  On the page, there is javascript to reference the div: `document.getElementById('divId')`.  This was working fine until another developer redesigned the page to use an ASP master page.

Now, `document.getElementById('divId')` returns null.  It appears that ASP.net prepends some characters to the names of elements within contents forms when you use a master page.  How can I know what the id of the div is when the page loads?

**Update** Allow me to give a specific example to clarify the question:  My page had a div with ID `divNotice`.  After changing my page to use a master page, I see when I print the source to the page that renders that the div ID is `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divNotice`.  My question is, how am I supposed to know what the div ID is going to be when the framework is done with it?

Comment: Can you look at the HTML sources of several pages produced by ASP.net (e.g., in a browser)?

Comment: What version of the framework are you using? 4.0 allows you to set the client ID mode of any server control so that it doesn't get mangled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that this is what you looking for.

```
document.getElementById('<%=divNotice.ClientID%>')
```

to get the ID of your element as appears on the html page use **.ClientID**

Hope this help.

Comment: does this mean that you actually have to put this line of JS inside the ASP page in question?

Comment: ACCEPTED: Not only does this answer my question, but it also helped me track down another issue that cropped up where a previous developer used `ClientID` and it needed to be `ID`

Comment: @meo there is many ways on how you can place the ClientID on the page, this is one of them, other is to place a literal control and render all the code inside him, other way is to register it as script, other way is to place the ids on some values of javascript with RegisterScript, ...

Comment: If you really wish to understand this in depth, a good description is given here: http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically create the javascript using Control.ClientID to determine the calculated ID of div.

```
document.getElementById('<%= DivControl.ClientID %>')
```

Or search for the element on the client side using the base ID as a search pattern.  See here:  [A generic way to find ASP.NET ClientIDs with jQuery](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/42319.aspx)

I prefer the server side calculation, but if you don't do it often and/or your current design prohibits it, the client side way is a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 1):

you can check i the element exists by checking if it returns not null

```
if (document.getElementById('divId') != null) { /* do your stuff*/ }
```

in other words:

```
if (document.getElementById('divId')) { /* do your stuff*/ }
```

---

now you have edited you orginal question i got it.. i would do something like this:

```
var arrDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    strDivName = "divId";

for (i=0;i<=arrDivs.length;i++){
    if( arrDivs[i].id.indexOf(strDivName) != -1) {
        alert("this is it")
    }
}
```

you can see a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pnHSw/2/

i think you could do it better with a regex.

But this is a pure JS way i don't know ASP.net

edit: i think Aristos solution is much cleaner :P

Comment: Obviously, I could.  My question is that since it seems that using a master page causes the ID to change, how can I know what to expect it to change to?

Comment: a control that is within another control and has a `runat="server"` tag can get what is basically a control hierarchy prepended to its name. So `myDiv` will get transformed to something like `ctl00_containerA_containerB_myDiv`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a descendent selector un css

```
<div id="wrapperControler">
    <controler id="controler"></controler>
</div>
```

## wrapperControler controler{

```
 dosomething;
```

}